# Can one use "in" type statements in C# and LINQ Lambda expressions?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I need from time to time to compare a number of values like:

```
if (myCurrentUser.Role in ("Admin","User"))
```

But it seems the above may not be possible, and instead one needs to do:

```
if (myCurrentUser.Role == "Admin" || myCurrentUser.Role == "User")
```

Which starts to gets quite long.

So is there a way to have an "in" approach. Obviously one can do this in SQL.

Also I would like to use this in LINQ Lambda expressions as well.

```
var myRecords = db.mytable.where(r=>r.name in ("Roy","Jack"))
```

currently I write this as:

```
var myRecords = db.mytable.where(r=>((r.name == "Roy")||(r.name == "Jack")));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `if (new [] { "Admin", "User" }.Contains(myCurrentUser.Role))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with `Contains`. Try this:

```
var names = new List<string>() { "Roy", "Jack" };
db.mytable.Where(r => names.Contains(r.name));
```

Comment: HOW DARE YOU STEAL MY PIC. (+1)

Answer (score 3):

try to use contains, something like:

```
var x = (new string[] {"A", "B"}).Contains("C");
```

Comment: The brackets are redundant, no?

Comment: yes, indeed. that's probably my bad habit too - i like make things explicit and more readable

Answer (score 2):

If you add this extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsIn<T>(this T source, params T[] values)
    {
        return values.Contains(source);
    }
}
```

You can write code like this:

```
if (myCurrentUser.Role.IsIn("Admin","User"))
```